# efecto hover al pasar sobre un elementos

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Tengo el sgte. problema, al estar mi mouse posicionado sobre el elemento ultimositemns todas los elementos tienen el efecto, es obvio por que todos tienen el mismo nombre en la clase mi pregunta es cual seria una alternativa para no tener varios nombres diferente de clases y que solo cambie el elemento sobre el cual este posicionado

```js
function foro_img() {

  $('.ultimositemns').on('mouseover', function() {
    $('.ultimositemns img').css("filter", "blur(2px)");
    $('.ultimositemns h5').css("font-size", "27px");
    $('.ultimositemns h5').css("background", "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0.19) 12%, rgba(0,0,0,0.51) 33%)");

    $('#vere').css("font-size", "100px");
  });
  $('.ultimositemns').on('mouseleave', function() {
    $('.ultimositemns img').css("filter", "blur(0px)");
    $('.ultimositemns h5').css("font-size", "0px");
    $('.ultimositemns h5').css("background", "transparent");
    $('#vere').css("font-size", "0");

  });



}
```

```css
.ultimositemns {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.botton-ver {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  left: 35%;
  top: 30%;
}

.vere {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #039BE5;
  transition: .3s;
  font-size: 0px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  color: white;
}

.ultimositemns img {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 300px;
  filter: blur(0px);
  transition: .8s;
}

.ultimositemns h5 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: none;
  z-index: 2;
  color: white;
  bottom: 0;
  background: none;
  font-size: 0px;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ultimositemns">
  <div class="botton-ver">
    <i class="vere" class="large material-icons">reply</i>
  </div>
  <h5>Ricardo Arjona 2017</h5>
  <img src="assets/img/foro/artista/holo1.jpg">
</div>
<div class="ultimositemns">
  <div class="botton-ver">
    <i class="vere" class="large material-icons">reply</i>
  </div>
  <h5>Nicky Jam 2017</h5>
  <img src="assets/img/foro/artista/holo2.jpg">
</div>
<div class="ultimositemns">
  <div class="botton-ver">
    <i class="vere" class="large material-icons">reply</i>
  </div>
  <h5>Shakira 2017</h5>
  <img src="assets/img/foro/artista/red.jpg">
</div>
<div class="ultimositemns">
  <div class="botton-ver">
    <i class="vere" class="large material-icons">reply</i>
  </div>
  <h5>Shakira 2017</h5>
  <img src="assets/img/foro/artista/holo3.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: Eso lo quieres hacer con jquery o directo con css?

Comment: no importa como, mientras funcione

Comment: Podrías hacer algo como esto desde css .ultimositemns img :hover {
  background: red;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa el objeto this por ejemplo:

```
$(this).css('background-color', 'red');
```

esto iría en la función del mouseover y solo aplicaría los cambios en el objeto seleccionado.

```
 $('.ultimositemns').on('mouseover', function() {
    $(this).find('img').css("filter", "blur(2px)");
    $(this).find('h5').css("font-size", "27px");

    $('#vere').css("font-size", "100px");
  });
```

Comment: Lo estoy aplicando, aguarda

Comment: Resuelto, Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
.ultimositemns {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: white;
  transition: .5s;
}

.ultimositemns :hover {
  background: red;
}
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: Recomendaría agregar una descripción, al menos de una línea, explicando qué estás usando